# how to show uploaded image to jsp page in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I am writing a program in spring mvc to upload and show image.
I save my project in `D:/SkillUp/Spring/UploadDemo` location.but when i upload image it successfully uploaded. I specified location to upload image in `WEB-INF/image` folder in my project Path.
Code of specify path is:

```
ServletContext context;

context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/image") + File.separator ;
```

but it save in this location

```
"D:\SkillUp\Spring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\UploadDemo\WEB-INF\image"
```

Now my question is how to show image that is uploaded to that location?

Comment: Can you format your code properly by adding 4 leading space to each line of code?

Comment: I got answer for my question-


1. In dispatcher-servlet.xml add below code


<mvc:resources mapping="/image/**" location="/WEB-INF/image/" />

2. for display in jsp page

<img alt="Uploaded Image" width="200" height="200" src="<c:url value="/image/"/>/${fileName}"/>

Answer (score 0):

Use this in front of your code

```
  **${pageContext.request.contextPath}**
```

Like this

```
"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/image" + File.separator ;
```

I am sure it will work for you.